# How to copy one object from one model to another model with Rails ActiveStorage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, copy, rails-activestorage

I'm currently using Rails 5.2.2.
I'm trying to copy one image between 2 models. So I want 2 files, and 2 entries in blobs and attachments.
My original object/image is on AWS S3.

My original model is *photo*, my target model is *image*.

I tried this:

```
image.file.attach(io: open(best_photo.full_url), filename: best_photo.filename, content_type: best_photo.content_type)
```

full_url is a method added in photo.rb:

```
include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
def full_url
  rails_blob_path(self.file, disposition: "attachment", only_path: true)
end
```

I got this error, as if the file was not found:

> No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen -
>   /rails/active_storage/blobs/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBHZz09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--2f865041b01d2f2c323a20879a855f25f231289d/881dc909-88ab-43b6-8148-5adbf888b399.jpg?disposition=attachment

I tried other different things such (this method is used when displaying images with image_tag() and works correctly:

```
def download_variant(version)
    variant = file_variant(version)
    return rails_representation_url(variant, only_path: true, disposition: "attachment")
  end
```

Same error.

I verified and the file is present on the S3 server.
What did I miss ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

You can attach the source blob to the target:

```
image.file.attach best_photo.file.blob
```

Comment: Please beware that this doesn't create a **copy**, but just references the original blob. If you have a `dependent: :purge_later` on one of the objects, this could cause some headaches...

Answer (score 6):

Updated for Rails 6+ - this worked for me

```
image.file.attach(io: StringIO.new(best_photo.download),
                  filename: best_photo.filename,
                  content_type: best_photo.content_type)
```

Answer (score 2):

OK, I got it.
I used *service_url*:

```
image.file.attach(io: open(best_photo.file_variant("large").service_url), filename: best_photo.file.blob.filename, content_type: best_photo.file.blob.content_type)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to use `file_blob` instead of `file.blob`

You can copy using `update`

```rb
image.update(file: best_photo.file_blob)
```

or `attach`

```rb
image.file.attach(best_photo.file_blob)
```

Both methods actually just create new blob association, there is no physical copying of attachment. So be careful when you call `image.blob.purge` or if you have `dependent: :purge_later`

If you want real copy you need to [read attachment](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#attaching-file-io-objects) with [`ActiveStorage::Blob#download`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveStorage/Blob.html#method-i-download)

```rb
image.file.attach(
  io: StringIO.new(best_photo.file.download),
  filename: best_photo.file.filename,
  content_type: best_photo.file.content_type
)
```

or with [`ActiveStorage::Blob#open`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveStorage/Blob.html#method-i-open)

```rb
best_photo.file_blob.open do |tempfile|
  image.file.attach(
    io: tempfile,
    filename: best_photo.file.filename,
    content_type: best_photo.file.content_type
  )
end
```

Be careful with large files